# Haar wavelet transformation of a binary vector data over $GF(2)$

Tags: signal-processing, image-processing, wavelets

I am trying to perform Haar wavelet transformation on the following vector which is defined over $GF(2)$.

$[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]$

I am doing it as follows.

$[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]$

$\implies [\frac{1 + 0}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1 + 0}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1 + 0}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1 + 0}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1 - 0}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1 - 0}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1 - 0}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1 - 0}{\sqrt{2}}]$

Now, we know that $\sqrt{2} \bmod 2 = 1 $.

$\implies [1 + 0, 1 + 0, 1 + 0, 1 + 0, 1 - 0, 1 - 0, 1 - 0, 1 - 0]$

$\implies [1 , 1, 1, 1 , 1 , 1, 1, 1]$

$\implies [\frac{1 + 1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1 + 1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1 - 1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1 - 1}{\sqrt{2}} , 1 , 1, 1, 1]$

$\implies [0, 0, 0, 0, 1 , 1, 1, 1]$

$\implies [\frac{0 + 0}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{0 - 0}{\sqrt{2}}, 0, 0, 1 , 1, 1, 1]$

$\implies [0, 0, 0, 0, 1 , 1, 1, 1]$

Did I do it write?

Comment: Any calculation claiming that $\sqrt2$ has value $1$ modulo $2$ looks suspicious to me. That is just so incompatible with $(\sqrt2)^2=2\equiv0\pmod2$ that anything may come out. But I am not aware of a $GF(2)$ valued Haar wavelet transform, so I am not saying anything with any degree of certainty. My experience in related transitions from $GF(2)$ to the reals does suggest that we may first remap the element $0\in GF(2)$ to the real number $+1$ and the element $1\in GF(2)$ to the real number $-1$. Please check with an appropriate source (or wait for a more knowledgeable person to show up).